# Como importo librerías o referencias en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola soy nuevo en C# y quiero realizar un pequeño programa de consola para usar una impresora, para ejecutarlo desde otra aplicación.

El problema es que revisando documentación debo usar System.Printing, pero cuando lo agrego con "using System.Printing" obtengo lo siguiente.

[image: Error que obtengo al usar use System.Printing]

Según leo hay que agregar una referencia de ensamblado, pero no se como hacerlo. Seguro es algo muy obvio, pero soy nuevo.

Intenté usar nuget para encontrar la referencia y ver si se solucionaba pero, no fué el caso.

Comment: Nuget es para instalar paquetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu proyecto agrega la referencia de esta forma, en `References`, da clic botón derecho del mouse y selecciona `Add Reference...`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busca en el listado y agrega `System.Printing`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Usar `System.Printing` en Aplicación de Consola (Console App)**

Debes abrir tu archivo .csproj y agregar:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Ejemplo:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


 <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

De esta forma podrás usar el namespace `System.Printing` :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias. 

Parece que mi estructura del proyecto es distinta, es solo una aplicación de consola. Y no me aparece en el Reference Manager el apartado de Assemblies, ¿tal vez no he creado el proyecto de forma correcta? lo que quiero hacer es un proyecto sin interfáz gráfica solo comandos.

Comment: Ok, actualicé la respuesta, perdón, no ví escribiste que era app de consola, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funcionó.